# spring injection works within user created instance?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I'm working with Spring, and I'm getting the injected instance as null when I create the instance with new operator, I can elobrate the scenario.

For example,
Let the class A and class B are injected into the class Main

```
      class Main
         {
       @autowired
      A a;
        @autowired
       B b;
```

```
    //getter and setter
   }

class MainExecute
{
 public static void main()
 {
   // loading the spring config xml 
 Main main = new  Main();
 A a=main.getA();
  // whether a will get the instance  ( I'm getting a as null) 

 }
```

what could be the reason for this scenario
Please guide me on the same

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your `spring-config.xml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate on the above answers:

You need to let the spring IOC container create your objects for you, you don't explicitly create them.  You can do this by creating a spring config xml file, here is a quick example:

**META-INF\spring\my-spring-config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

<bean id="myMainClass" class="org.foo.Main" />
<bean id="myA" class="org.foo.A" />
<bean id="myB" class="org.foo.B" />

</beans>
```

**org.foo.MainExecute:**

```
class MainExecute
{
 public static void main()
 { 

  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF\\spring\\my-spring-config.xml");
  Main main = (Main) appContext.getBean("myMainClass");

   }
}
```

In this example the Spring IOC container will instantiate an "A" bean and a "B" bean.  It will then autowire these into the "Main" bean.

Comment: Thank you for example Derek, I've one more question. Am working on web Application and I've registered the context listener in web.xml. Is there any way to get the appContext without loading the xml through ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. Is there any way some think like this
UriInfo.getApplicationContext().getBean("myMainClass");

Comment: If I understand your question correctly I think this might be what you are looking for:  http://www.objectpartners.com/2010/08/23/gaining-access-to-the-spring-context-in-non-spring-managed-classes/

Answer (score 5):

No, it won't get dependency injection.

Only objects created/managed by the spring container will get the facilities offered by spring dependency injection.